# Figure out why Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Build() returns false

Tags: c#, build, csproj

I'm trying to build C# projects using .csproj files.
For this I'm using the following code:

```
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project project = new Microsoft.Build.EvaluationProject(projectFile);
bool success = project.Build();
```

But not all projects are build and for some I get `false` as the result of `project.Build()`.
Any ideas how to understand what is going wrong?

Or maybe anyone can suggest an alternative way to compile projects using .csproj files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an `ILogger` to the `Build` method as a parameter. I suggest implementing one [as the MSDN article suggests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.utilities.logger.aspx). Just copy paste their code, add any missing references and you'll be fine.

Then you can call `Build` as follows:

```
Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project project = new Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project(projectFile);
BasicFileLogger logger = new BasicFileLogger();
logger.Parameters = logFilePath;
logger.Verbosity = LoggerVerbosity.Normal; //Increase it if you don't get enough data
bool success = project.Build(logger);
```

The example logger will write all data that you would see during a normal build to the file at `logFilePath`. Based on that you should be able to discern the issue.